# Network switch in WIndows 10

Tags: windows, networking, switch, bridge

I have 2 physical ethernet connections: Ethernet1 andEthernet2 on PC_A. Ethernet1 is connected to the router (DHCP). What I am trying to accomplish, is to enable a switch between Ethernet1 and Ethernet2, co PC_B can have access to the local network and Internet:

[image]

PC_B Ethernet is also DHCP configured. How to accomplish this functionality in Windows 10? Internet share functionality creates a subnetwork for the ETH2. Creating a bridge and adding Ethernet1 and Ethernet2 to it leaves both machines without internet. I would appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way to go was to create the bridge after all. I have followed this guide: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10

The part I was missing was that I had to set a static IP for the bridge for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will want to enable internet connection sharing for you PC_A. Try going to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections. Select the Network adapter you want to share, right-click go to properties, then 'sharing'.

Might be a start.

[image]

Comment: I did that. The problem is that the ethernet2 was not exposing the network from ethernet1- it created a new sub network. I need to access the router from pc_B (the router should see pc_B and providenit with ip address via dhcp).